# Creating for loop using tq_get function from the tidyquant library to get unemployment filings by state in R? [Image & Code Included]

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, quantmod

**Goal:** I want to get initial unemployment filings by state in a table for every state in the U.S.

Here is the example I am following: [Link](https://rviews.rstudio.com/2020/04/16/state-unemployment-claims/?utm_content=buffere1d4b&utm_medium=social&utm_source=linkedin&utm_campaign=buffer)

**Here is a quick snippet of the code from that link:**

```
ga_claims <- 
  "GAICLAIMS" %>% 
  tq_get(get = "economic.data", 
         from = "1999-01-01") %>% 
  rename(claims = price)
```

That first filter is for Georgia. However, I want it for **all states**. I was able to create a csv file to concatenate all state abbreviations with the 'ICLAIMS'. I simply want to pass a for loop through my function you see below. Attached is a screenshot of the csv I uploaded that has all the states with in that format...'CAICLAIMS', 'NYICLAIMS', 'ALICLAIMS' and so on...

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can create a function :

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyquant)

get_data <- function(x) {
  x %>% 
    tq_get(get = "economic.data",from = "1999-01-01") %>% 
    rename(claims = price) 
}
```

and pass each `Claim_Code` through `lapply`.

```
lapply(df$Claim_Code, get_data)
```

If you want to combine this into one dataframe, we can do :

```
do.call(rbind, Map(cbind, lapply(df$Claim_Code, get_data), 
               Claim_Code = df$Claim_Code))

#         date claims Claim_Code
#1   1999-01-02   9674  GAICLAIMS
#2   1999-01-09  19455  GAICLAIMS
#3   1999-01-16  20506  GAICLAIMS
#4   1999-01-23  12932  GAICLAIMS
#5   1999-01-30  10871  GAICLAIMS
#6   1999-02-06   7997  GAICLAIMS
```

OR using `purrr`.

```
library(purrr)
map2_df(map(df$Claim_Code, get_data), df$Claim_Code, cbind)
```

**data**

```
df <- data.frame(Claim_Code = c('GAICLAIMS', 'ALICLAIMS', 'AZICLAIMS'), 
                 stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Comment: thank you for the quick response, every time I run the lapply function I am transferred to a new window and I get the message in my console "Called from: tq_get(., get = "economic.data", from = "1999-01-01")
Browse[1]> "

Comment: Did you add `browser()` somewhere in the function? Looks like there was a debugger attached somewhere in the function.